# How do I gracefully handle closing a websocket when one endpoint is still readying data to send?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, websocket

I have a NodeJS server that does asynchronous processing after receiving data from the client through a websocket. When it's finished processing, it sends data back to the client.

I've run into a case where the connection is closed abnormally while the server is still processing data. There's no way to interrupt it, and if it tries sending through a closed socket, my server crashes.

Worst case is I wrap the send() calls in a check that confirms the socket is open, but this feels dirty. Does the fact that it crashes indicate a bug in the node module I'm using (ws)? Am I misunderstanding the Websocket spec somehow?

Comment: Perhaps this could be of help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326413/node-js-websocket-crashes-when-client-disconnect